# GQL not working when I select a particular field

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have an entity called with columns app, id, params, view, timestamp. **When I do a select * in GQL it works fine.** Screenshot attached below.

[image]

However **when I try to select only one column I don't see any results**. Screenshot attached below.

[image]

Also when **I try to apply a where clause again I don't see any** results. 
[image]

I tried a where clause for **another entity and it worked fine**. [image]

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Regards,
Sathya

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to querying an entity with unindexed property. An entity with an unindexed property behaves as if the property were not set: queries with a filter or sort order on the unindexed property will never match that entity.

More info : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes#Unindexed_Properties

Comment: Thanks Nijin. I will create an index and check it out again.

Comment: @Sathya did it work? It looks like each entity is indexed and you can define index only for multiple entities.